# Why does this program crash?

Tags: c, crash, physics

I need this to run so I can analyze some data from my lab. However, when the program runs and I type the value for "n" it simply crashes. Any tips on how to correct this?

Thanks, here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


int main()
{
  FILE *magfield;
  FILE *means;
  FILE *variances;
  double *mean;
  double *variance;
  double field[12000];
  double time[12000];
  double sum=0, squares=0;
  int i, j=0, k=0, l=0, n=0;
  magfield=fopen("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\Homework\\ILab\\magneticfield.txt","r");
  means=fopen("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\Homework\\ILab\\means.txt","w");
  variances=fopen("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\Homework\\ILab\\variances.txt","w");

  for (i=0;i<12000;i++)
  {
       fscanf(magfield,"%f %f", &time[i], &field[i]);
       //printf("%f %f\n", time[i], field[i]);
  }

  printf("How many data points would you like to be analyzed at a time?\n");
  scanf("%i", &n);

  mean=(double*)calloc(n,sizeof(double));
  variance=(double*)calloc(n,sizeof(double));

  for (i=0;i<12000;i+=n)
  {
      for(j=i;j<n;j++)
      {
          sum+=field[j];
          squares+=field[j]*field[j];
      }
      mean[k]=sum/n;
      variance[k]=squares/n-(mean[k]*mean[k]);
      fprintf(means,"%f\n", mean[k]);
      fprintf(variances,"%f\n", variance[k]);
      sum=0;
      squares=0;
      k++;
  }
  free(mean);
  free(variance);
  printf("Press enter to continue...\n");
  getch();  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the "crashing message"?

Comment: Tip: use a debugger.

Comment: Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: Lab3.exe
  Application Version: 0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp: 51241b06
  Fault Module Name: ntdll.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.17725
  Fault Module Timestamp: 4ec49b8f
  Exception Code: c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0003331f
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Comment: Cicada, what do you use for a debugger?

Comment: There are so many bad coding habits here and you've provided so little information that it's impossible to tell. Use a debugger (as has been suggested) to see where the crash is occurring.  Then ask.

Comment: c00000005 is an Access Violation error. You are probably cloberring memory somewhere and overwriting a buffer.  Use a debugger and/or at least put some printfs in your loops to see if you have an out-of-bounds index on an array.

Comment: This is running on Windows.  Are you using An MS tool like Visual Studio? Debugger built in.  Debugger is your friend.  Get to know it.  You also don't check if the fopen calls return a valid FILE*, or null.  HOw do you know the files are being read/written to properly?

Comment: I'm using wxDev, and I had checks to make sure the files are being read and written properly but I've removed them to narrow my search for the bug. What debugger do you suggest?

Comment: If you insert assertions strategically, and look for assertion failures before asking, you won't need a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest `#include <assert.h>` and `assert(magfield != NULL); assert(means != NULL); assert(variances != NULL);` after your fopens. In addition, you should probably `assert(fscanf(...) == 2);` and `assert(scanf(...) == 1);`. These are debugging aids: If anything fails, you'll know it is because of missing files or unexpected input. `assert(mean != NULL); assert(variance != NULL);` to ensure those are allocated successfully. Which assertion can you place to ensure k is always less than n? How can you ensure you don't access mean[k] or variance[k] when k is an invalid index for mean or variance?

What does [this page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/scanf.html) tell you about the type that the `%f` format specifier deals with? What is the type of `&time[i]` and `&field[i]`? The answers to those questions should be identical, otherwise you're dealing with undefined behaviour.

Why are you using the non-portable getch from the non-standard conio.h, when you could just use the portable getchar from the standard stdio.h for the same purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You've got the size of `mean` and `variance` arrays wrong. You allocate them to be of size `n` elements, but then you have your outer loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < 12000; i += n)
{
    ...
    mean[k] = sum/n;
    variance[k] = squares/n - (mean[k]*mean[k]);
    ...
    k++;
}
```

The body of the loop would execute `12000/n` times, which for any `n` smaller than the square root of `12000` (110) would result in more than `n` iterations, hence `k` would grow big enough so that out-of-bound access past the end of both arrays would occur.

On a completely different notice, your inner loop doesn't seem correct. Perhaps it should be:

```
for (j = i; j < i+n; j++)
{
   sum += field[j];
   squares += field[j]*field[j];
}
```

(you also have to make sure that `i+n` does not get bigger than `12000`)